# Populating a recordset between two positions in a table using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a query that will only return a recordset between 2 positions in a table

[image]

For example, using Excel to demonstrate, populate a recordset between positions 3 and 7

I thought about using BETWEEN with the ID field, but there may be times that a record has been deleted and the ID field auto-incrementation will be out.

Ultimately, I want to use the query to populate a list for reporting:

Page 1 shows Records 1 to 10
Page 2 shows Records 11 to 20
Page 3 shows Records 21 to 30 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `limit` and `offset`?

```
select t.*
from t
order by id
limit 10 offset 0;
```

Then for subsequent pages, you would have:

```
limit 10 offset 9;
limit 10 offset 19;
```